# HTML divs seem to not line up at certain zoom levels

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a header that has 3 sections, each spanning 1/3 of the page.

```
.container-header {
            color: white;
            background: #28939D;
            height: 48px;
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-left: 24px;
}

<div style='width:calc(100% / 3);'>
    <div class='container-header'>
        <svg width='26' height='29' viewBox='0 0 26 29' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
            <path fill-rule='evenodd' clip-rule='evenodd' d='<code needed to make the icons>' fill='white'/>
        </svg>
        <p class='header-text'></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each of the 3 has the same svg size information and the same parent style of width being 33%.

Unfortunately the bottom edge of the middle section seems to bleed out a pixel or two depending on zoom level, and the left side of it sometimes has an almost-white border. Below are images at the normal fully zoomed out scale, zooming in a bit, and then zooming in as much as I can. The HTML becomes a PDF and the screenshots were taken from the PDF view (not an actual HTML page displayed in a browser.)

Fully zoomed out[image]

Zoomed in a bit[image]

Zoomed in even more[image]

Anyone seen anything like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the flexbox to control the menu layout, check this sample:

```css
.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  background: deepskyblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row no-wrap;
  border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

.navigation li {
  flex: 1 0;
}

.navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  background: #00b7f5;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This should be close enough to get me where I need to go, thanks!

Comment: Happy to help, voteup so other can see it’s helpful